# How to make FileSystemWatcher wait to raise the Created Event until the Directory is named?

Tags: c#, events, filesystemwatcher

I have a `FileSystemWatcher` which triggers an `OnCreated` Event when a new Directory is created.  But the directories name is always the default name(newDirectory(1)).

Is there a possibility to wait until the directories name is confirmed? (the users focus gets out of the ordners name textbox)

Comment: So far as the file system is concerned, the creation of the directory and a subsequent renaming operation are two completely unrelated events. You shouldn't expect something hooked into the file system to try to relate them

Comment: @CarlSixsmith - I'd image "Ordner" is "Folder" in JJJJs language.

Comment: @CarlSixsmith “Neuer Ordner” is German.

Comment: Yes but what should I do then when I have to do something when a new directory is created and need the name of the directory for it?

Comment: If you want the new name, then also listen to the rename event and only trigger your code delayed so you can be sure that the user completed creating and renaming the folder.

Comment: Given that there's no guarantee that the user *will* rename the folder, the best you can do is apply a heuristic and wait some amount of time to see if a rename happens. Either that or invent a time machine so that you can *know* that the user will be performing a rename operation.

Comment: Don't confuse directory creation with renaming. Explorer creates a directory with a specific name and displays a UI for renaming. If the user hits Escape, the rename operation never happens but the directory is still there. On the other hand, an `md` command will simply create a folder with the given name. FWS is working properly, your code needs to handle the *actual* events

Answer (score 0):

You cant directly hook both the creation and naming of folder (which is obviously two events). Instead you can create your own customized class in which you can achieve the goal. Here is the sample code:

```
class FolderCreationWatcher
{
    private FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    private string lastFileName = string.Empty;
    public delegate void OnFolderCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e);
    public event OnFolderCreated FolderCreated;

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    public FolderCreationWatcher(string dirPath, int timeOut)
    {
        watcher.Path = dirPath;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        watcher.Created += watcher_Created;
        timer.Interval = timeOut;
        timer.Enabled = false;
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
    }

    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.NotifyFolderCreated();
    }

    private void watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        lastFileName = e.Name;
        watcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    void OnRenamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OldName.Equals(lastFileName))
        {
            lastFileName = e.Name;
            this.NotifyFolderCreated();
        }
    }

    private void NotifyFolderCreated()
    {
        if (FolderCreated != null)
            FolderCreated(this, new FileSystemEventArgs(WatcherChangeTypes.Created, watcher.Path, lastFileName));
        timer.Enabled = false;
        watcher.Renamed -= OnRenamed;
    }
```

This class usage will be something like this:

```
FolderCreationWatcher folderWatcher = new FolderCreationWatcher(dirPath, 5000);
        folderWatcher.FolderCreated += OnFolderCreated;

    void OnFolderCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do Something
    }
```